# What other web analytics tools are out there?

Tags: web-analytics-tools

What other web analytics tools people use other than google analytics?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Webtrends
- Webalizer (C)
- AWStats (Perl)
- Smarterstats

Did you want free ones? 2 of those aren't, but webalizer is quite poor. AWStats is decent and free. Plus [google "web stats"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=website+stats) and you get hundreds of commercial ones.

Or the open directory links:

- [Log analysis](http://www.google.com/Top/Computers/Software/Internet/Site_Management/Log_Analysis/Freeware_and_Open_Source/) (Free/open source)
- [Log analysis](http://www.google.com/Top/Computers/Software/Internet/Site_Management/Log_Analysis/Commercial/) (Commercial ones)

If you're in the mood to finish a project, I got 1/3 through [writing one](http://www.codeplex.com/Statmagic) in C# :) Unfortunately the most important part - the eye candy reporting - was never finished. But the parsing was done.

Comment: These tool are log analysers. I'm not sure they can be compared with Google Analytics.

Comment: They do exactly the same thing as google analytics, but via a log file not javascript. Google analytics misses one step, but at the same time misses some features log files can show like 404s,500 pages and (slightly) faster loading pages

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood the original question (which wasn't about the "how") and your answer is totally valid.

Comment: Erm, Chris no you're wrong. Google Analytics and the like can easily tag 404s and the like.  The main difference is that JavaScript analytics system get around caching.  Because of this, log file analytics are worse than useless for anything other than gauging server requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with it but this seem to be the most "famous" open source solution:

- [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) (Open Source)

These are other commercial solutions:

- [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com/) (Free during beta)
- [Clicky Web Analytics](http://www.getclicky.com/)
- [Compete](http://www.compete.com/)
- [ClickTale](http://www.clicktale.com/)

I have no idea of their usage statistic. I wonder why someone would pay for this kind of service.

Comment: They look nicely branded/markted but as you say, a bit strange why you would pay for the service when google offers it for free

Comment: Clicky is completely realtime, where Analytics is not. I've been able to respond to what my users are doing. Just because something is free it doesn't mean it is any good for all cases.

Comment: Most of my customers pay for it because: (a) they don't want to run a server farm, (b) they like having someone to call when things aren't working right, and (c) they're not developers but they need to track web conversions.

Comment: And, I thought Compete was a data mining company that somehow samples user behavior and then reports on it (for money.) They analyze data, but it's internet-wide, not for your site alone, I think.

Answer (score 1):

[Mint](http://www.haveamint.com/) is nice, very pretty, lots of features, and not very expensive at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to spend a lot of money and time, try out Omniture SiteCatalyst.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy-to-use, real-time, high-performance tracking and reporting system which lets you download all of your data (if you want), you can try my company:

[ConversionRuler conversion tracking](http://www.ConversionRuler.com/?_cr=comments|stackoverflow)

We track sites which gets 10M+ page view per month without a hiccup, and have dozens of agency clients who track 30+ clients using our tools. Many of them use us as an alternative to Omniture and WebTrends to save on their enormous costs.

Not for everyone, but worth a look. We focus on "less is more", and we're not a *search engine who you may not want to give your data to*, especially if you're paying them for traffic. (e.g. Google Analytics, Urchin, and Yahoo! Analytics)

My $0.02.

Answer (score 0):

[Reinvigorate](http://reinvigorate.net/) - seems like they're always in beta registrations though. One upcoming feature they do mention is being able see heat map reports.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113/software-for-webserver-log-analysis) with a comparison of metrics. It is meant as a warning against using Awstats and the like.
Just because a tool produces number and colorful charts, it does not mean it is any good.

I posted a screen shot of the Woopra live analytics capabilities in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344693/looking-for-real-time-web-server-analytics-package).